# How to redirect back to previous page after post request in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I have a system where user enters the date range from and to and gets all required data between that date range. Data retrieved from the database shows in the table containing checkbox to each row. When user Check the check box and submit the data it updates to the database, but I'm have to redirect to the same table after updating the data in database. It says the GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. Need Help.

Here is my Date range fill view.

```html
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<div class="input-group" style="margin:50px">
  <table>
    <form action="/payment_list_table" method="POST">
      @csrf
      <div class="form-outline">
        <tr>
          <th>
            <label>From</label>
          </th>
          <th>
            <input type="date"  name= 'from' class="form-control" placeholder="Doc Received Date" required="" />
          </th>
          <th>
            <label>To</label>
          </th>
          <th>
            <input type="date"  name= 'to' class="form-control" placeholder="Doc Received Date" required="" />
          </th>
        </tr>                        
        <th>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
          </button>
        </th>
      </div>
    </form>
  </table>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here is my Search Table View

```html
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<div class='container' style="margin-top:50px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-group" style="margin:20px">
      <form>
        <table style="float:right">
          <th>
            <div class="form-outline">
              <input type="search" id="form1" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
          </th>                        
      </form>
    </div>
    <form method="POST">
      @csrf
      <button type="submit" formaction="#" name="submit" class="checklistpo">PO</button>
      <button type="submit" formaction="#" name="submit" class="ajax.po">AO</button>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table custom-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">
                  <label class="control control--checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="js-check-all"/>
                    <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                  </label>
                </th>
                <th scope="col" >S.N</th>
                <th scope="col">LC NO</th>
                <th scope="col">Applicant</th>
                <th scope="col">Doc Value</th>
                <th scope="col">Doc Received date</th>
                <th scope="col">LC Type</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php $number = 1;?>
              @foreach($datas as $items)
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist[]" value="{{$items->id}}" /></td>
                  <td>{{$number}}</td>
                  <td>{{$items->lc_no}}</td>
                  <td>{{$items->applicant}}</td>
                  <td>{{$items->doc_value}}</td>
                  <td>{{$items->rec_date}}</td>
                  <td>{{$items->sight_usance}}</td>                 
                </tr>
                <?php $number++; ?>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  @endsection
```

Here is my Controller

```php
function po(Request $req){
  $validate=Validator::make($req->all(), [
    "checkboxlist" => "required|array"
  ]);

  foreach($req->checkboxlist as $list){
    $data = Doc::find($list);
    $data->payment_comment = "PO";
    $data->Payment_status = "Prepared";
    $data->save();
  };

  return Redirect::back();
    
  if($validate->fails()){
    return redirect()->back()->with("errors",$validate->errors());
  }
}
```

And My Route

```php
Route::post('po', [PaymentController::class, 'po']);
```

Comment: You want to redirect back to this route `Route::post('po',[PaymentController::class, 'po']);` ? If so, then you can't

Comment: It should be simply `return back()->with(...)`; you're not specifying the route you want to redirect to, so there shouldn't be any reason you get that error. What route are you posting from? Typical flow is `GET` request to see the form -> `POST` request -> `REDIRECT` -> `GET` to the form you posted from.

Comment: @Espresso then how can i make user to redirect to the table page...

Comment: `return redirect()->route('route_to_table_page')`, but there's currently no reason you should be getting that error.

Comment: @TimLewis One question...How does page knows the same date range i inserted at first to get to the table after refresh.

Comment: Your redirect route need to be `GET` you can create one with same URI prefix `Route::get('po', [PaymentController::class, 'po']);`

Comment: For that, you'll need `withInput()`, like `return redirect()->route(...)->withInput()`, then `value="{{ old('from') }}"` and `value="{{ old('to') }}"` on your `<input>` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs a bit of formatting & make more understandable variables but anyways. You need to check if validation fails before foreach. `return redirect()->back();` is the right way to go back.

```
function po(Request $req)
{
    $validate = Validator::make($req->all(), [
        "checkboxlist" => "required|array"
    ]);

    if ($validate->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->with("errors", $validate->errors());
    }
    
    foreach ($req->checkboxlist as $list) {
        $data = Doc::find($list);
        $data->payment_comment = "PO";
        $data->Payment_status = "Prepared";
        $data->save();
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: This looks great, 1 note though, `return back()` is a shortcut for `return redirect()->back()`; makes the code a bit shorter/easier to read 

Comment: I says "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Comment: @TimLewis true that, just tried. I guess i didn't catch up with the latest news :D

Comment: So what to do now...any solution?

Comment: Im not sure about this one judging on your code but i believe it's because of the $data->save() inside your foreach

Comment: You can totally remove the `if` if you just do `Validator::validate` (and don't even store it in `$validate`). It will automatically redirect back with `['errors' => validator errors]`.